# What's the fastest way to brush up on algorithms for a technical interview (on Monday)?

Tags: algorithm

I have a technical interview on Monday and they were kind enough to give me a heads-up to brush up on my basic algorithms. It's been years since I looked at that kind of stuff and I'm pretty weak on it to begin with so I generally have a bad feeling about this. What's the best way to review the basics and get some practice in before Monday?

Comment: Read some background material rather than posting on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Starting [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net) might help you, also try picking up [Algorithms in a Nutshell](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596516246) and working through those examples. Should be do-able in a weekend.

Answer (score 7):

1. [TopCoder Algorithm Tutorials](http://www.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=alg_index)
2. Get the [Algorithm Design Manual](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387948600) and look at the reference section. It has a nice "Problem -> Algorithm" cheat sheet.

Answer (score 6):

Also take a look at questions on StackOverflow that are tagged `Algorithm`.

They might actually turn up in the interview ;)

Best of Luck!

Comment: direct link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algorithm

Answer (score 3):

This [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445425/what-algorithms-should-every-developer-know) would be helpful. Also, mostly you should know about

```
* Sorting
* Searching
* Inserting and removing from various data structures
```

As this are the main algorithms which are normally asked in the interviews.

*Note: This is from my personal experience and it may differ from person to person.

Comment: Not sure as to why this question has been downvoted ?

Comment: The linked SO question had been deleted and is not available any more :(

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_algorithms

Especially the Search, Item Search and Sorting sections.